# How can I run vscode with sudo on osx?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

[Edit] VSCode just makes this work these days...

`code ./.zshrc`

---

I want to use vs code to edit .bash_profile

I setup the bash command (ala https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/setup)

> > edit... command prompt setup is now here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac

if I type "sudo code .bash_profile" - I get "sudo: code: command not found"

Thanks - Chad

Comment: Can you run `code .bash_profile`? In other words, is `code` an actual command that is in the path? Apparently your system cannot find the `code` command.

Comment: It is setup as a bash command as directed on the linked page - function code () { VSCODE_CWD="$PWD" open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args $*; } -- code command works fine when not running sudo

Comment: Don't do that. Mac OS X applications are not intended to be run as root, and doing so will have undesirable effects.

Comment: surely running an editor as root can't be that bad... if nano and vi work, why not code / atom / whatever...

Comment: `sudo code <file>` should work. I just tried.

Answer (score 27):

The following should do it:

```
sudo /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron
```

Comment: `sudo "/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron" ~/.bash_profile` did the trick - thanks!

Comment: Looking at https://askubuntu.com/questions/803343/how-to-run-visual-studio-code-as-root, the command `sudo code --user-data-dir="~/.vscode-root"` worked for me.

Comment: sudo /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron to be fair is the correct line :)

Comment: It works, but does have another way? Can i put my user in a group of _www:_www? If has, i do not have to enter in Code by terminal.

Answer (score 13):

In case of a default installation (e.g.: under default applications folder)

Try running

`sudo open /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app`

After you make a save on a protected file it will ask you, then just hit overwrite it will prompt for your sudo password.

if you are not sure about the location of you VSCode app, just drag and drop the icon from where it is to the terminal, it will print the path automatically after the dragging, after that just exec `sudo open` command and append the path, in my case was the one above, hope this helps!

Answer (score 8):

The problem is the git folder has no permission to the user save in it.

```
sudo chown -R youruser git_folder/
```

That's the way I solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Try Below Command :

`sudo /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code`

Comment: Looks like this is what works now (Big Sur & VSCode 1.59.0)