# cannot update php 7 cli in my mac

Tags: php

To install php7 I run:

```
curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.1  
php -v
```

It show php `5.6.30`

Then, I run this in my terminal:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH
php-v
```

It show the latest version of php : 7.1 .

When I closing the terminal and run the `php -v` again.
it show the old version php again `5.6.30`

Why is this happening?

Comment: Because running `export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH` in a terminal applies only to the current terminal session. You need to add the line to whatever file is run on terminal start on OSX. Under linux this would usually be `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: @JonStirling ..so what should I do??

Comment: A quick google search tells me you should add that line to `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: alright , thanks. try it now

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34861791/how-can-i-run-vscode-with-sudo-on-osx this helped me . thanks