# bash: ng: command not found only in Visual Studio Code

Tags: angular, macos, visual-studio-code, macos-big-sur

I'm trying to execute `ng` commands in visual studio code but getting the error : `bash: ng: command not found`.

I have changed some configurations reading in other posts and everything works great in the MacOs terminal , while in visual Studio Code it prompts the above message.

What should I do in order to fix this?

Comment: Did you restart VSCode? Did you restart your Mac?

Comment: Did you restart your terminal and check if the `ng` command is still available? I suspect that the changes to the `$PATH` are not persistent.

Answer (score 0):

is Angular globally installed on your system? you can try this again with

```
npm i -g @angular/cli
```

This will not affect your project's angular version. (as long as you add the -g)
I am assuming you are using Linux/MacOS. If it still doesnt work, use

```
PATH=$PATH:[path_to_your_user_profile]/path-to-npm
```

To make sure your NPM is added to your path

Comment: Seems i misread the question. I thought ng only did work in VScode. Please try running VScode as administrator

Comment: running as admin in macOs is possible? how can I do that?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34864397/8459367). Opening it with `sudo` will always do it as admin. or root in your case

Comment: I don't think that will change anything. To read the files necessary to run the Angular CLI, no sudo should be necessary.

Comment: @JSONDerulo perhaps.. but the in IDE shell uses terminal commands. Where in this case "ng" is used

Comment: @SvenElmendorp I am a newbie with MacOs. how can I find the path to npm?

Comment: @YanivEliav `/usr/local/bin/npm`. but you might want to verify this first

Answer (score 0):

What is the version of node in your terminal. Check with the following command

```
node -v
```

If the node version is far less, it will not detect ng command since ng is installed in the node_modules of a different node version.
This might be because the nvm default version is < version supported by Angular CLI.

I fixed the issue using the following command -

```
nvm alias default node
```

This will make the latest node version installed in your system as the new node default version which will persist in new termina windows.

Additionaly, I was facing an issue because of the lines inserted by `npm install -g @angular/cli` in ~/.zshrc -

```
source <(ng completion script)
```

If you're getting error for compdef like `n/dev/fd/12:18: command not found: compdef`, adding the following line above source ng completion command fixed it for me -

```
autoload -U +X compinit && compinit
```